# Redshift Postgresql - How to Parse Nested JSON

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to parse a JSON text using JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT() function. 
JSON sample:

```
{ 
   "data":[ 
      { 
         "name":"ping",
         "idx":0,
         "cnt":27,
         "min":16,
         "max":33,
         "avg":24.67,
         "dev":5.05
      },
      { 
         "name":"late",
         "idx":0,
         "cnt":27,
         "min":8,
         "max":17,
         "avg":12.59,
         "dev":2.63
      }
   ]
}
'
```

I tried   *JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(event , '{"name":"late"}', 'avg')*  function to get 'avg' for name = "late", but it returns blank. 
Can anyone help, please?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a rather complicated task in Redshift, that, unlike Postgres, has [poor support to manage JSON](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/json-functions.html), and no function to unnest arrays.

Here is one way to do it using a number table; you need to populate the table with incrementing numbers starting at `0`, like:

```
create table nums as
    select 0 i union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 
    union all select 4 union all select 5 n union all select 6 
    union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
;
```

Once the table is created, you can use it to walk the JSON array using `json_extract_array_element_text()`, and check its content with `json_extract_path_text()`:

```
select json_extract_path_text(item, 'avg') as my_avg
from (
    select json_extract_array_element_text(t.items, n.i, true) as item
    from (
        select json_extract_path_text(mycol, 'data', true ) as items
        from mytable
    ) t
    inner join nums n on n.i < json_array_length(t.items, true)
) t
where json_extract_path_text(item, 'name') = 'late';
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use `json_array_elements` for that:

```
select obj->'avg'
  from foo f, json_array_elements(f.event->'data') obj 
where obj->>'name' = 'late';
```

[Working example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4RYbdg71ksxt4KJFN8gc2r/0)

```
create table foo (id int, event json);
insert into foo values (1,'{ 
   "data":[ 
      { 
         "name":"ping",
         "idx":0,
         "cnt":27,
         "min":16,
         "max":33,
         "avg":24.67,
         "dev":5.05
      },
      { 
         "name":"late",
         "idx":0,
         "cnt":27,
         "min":8,
         "max":17,
         "avg":12.59,
         "dev":2.63
      }]}');
```